# Sponsoring or Advertising a gambling-gaming platform

Tags: money

Assalamualikum , as we all know gambling is haram however i would like to know if i get a sponsorship from a betting game company / online casino as they say. I will have to put up their banner in my platform somewhere so my audience will see the banner and maybe just maybe be interested in that platform. Is taking money from this haram? does this come under gambling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assalāmu `alaikum Warahmatullāhi Wabrakatuh,

Earning income from Haram sources is Haram. A sponsorship from a betting company is haram. You are leading people to do haram and earning income from it.

طَلَبُ كَسْبِ الْحَلَالِ فَرِيضَةٌ بَعْدَ الْفَرِيضَةِ

Earning of Halal income is an obligation beyond other obligations.

(Shu‛bul Imān lil bayhaqi #8367 , 11/175)

Betting is haram (completely prohibited). This is expressly prohibited in the Quran.

Allah says,
يَسْأَلُونَكَ عَنِ الْخَمْرِ وَالْمَيْسِرِ قُلْ فِيهِمَا إِثْمٌ كَبِيرٌ وَمَنَافِعُ لِلنَّاسِ وَإِثْمُهُمَا أَكْبَرُ مِنْ نَفْعِهِمَا

They ask you regarding wine and gambling; Say in them both is great sin and (although)
there is (some) benefit (in them) for the people but their sin is greater than their benefit.

(Qur’an 2:219)

Allah Ta’ala says,
وَلَا تَعَاوَنُوا عَلَى الْإِثْمِ

And do not assist in sin
(Qur’an 5:2)

And Allah Ta’āla Knows Best.